# After updating Realtek driver wifi option gone

Tags: 16.04, wireless

[image]

After installing Realtek driver RTL8822AE , wifi option not showing.

**`ifconfig`** output:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:e1:ad:28:2b:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.114  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::95dd:1300:11ed:fe1b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61505934 (61.5 MB)  TX bytes:5689194 (5.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1346 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1346 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:228143 (228.1 KB)  TX bytes:228143 (228.1 KB)
```

Comment: which kernel are you using? Ubuntu kernels 4.4 and newer require signed kernel modules if secure boot is on

Comment: How did you install the driver? Compile from source code??

Comment: Kernel version: 4.10.0-33-generic.

I have used this  [Blog](https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa) for installing driver.